# Child Height Of Parent Height On Hover

Tags: html, css

I would like my parent div on hover to pass its height to the child div. Yet I can not seem to do this correctly :( Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<ul class="sidebarbuttons2">
    <li><a href="#"> <h1> Title </h1> </a>
        <ul class="dropdownbuttonsholder row">
            <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem1" class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"> Item 1 </a></ul>
            <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem2" class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"> Item 2 </a></ul>
            <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem3" class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"> Item 3 </a></ul>
            <ul id="dropdownbuttonitem4" class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"> Item 4 </a></ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then I am trying this CSS, but it will not accomplish what I am trying to do:

```
.sidebarbuttons2    {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebarbuttons2:hover {
    min-height: 100px;
}

.dropdownbuttonsholder  {
    display: none;
}               

.sidebarbuttons2:hover .dropdownbuttonsholder:hover     {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

So basically the normal height is 50px, and then when a user hovers over it the div expands to 100px, and so does the dropdown (which just floats over the box). Now my problem is the dropdown stays at 50px, and does NOT go to 100px. Do you get what the problem is? :( I would basically like the dropdown to expand to the full 100% of hovered div.

Answer (score 1):

just remove hover in dropdownbuttonsholder in the last rule

```
.sidebarbuttons2:hover .dropdownbuttonsholder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that, the 100% is equal to 50px, not the 100px which it shoould be

Comment: Sorry I have been busy. Ok so currently I want it to grab 100% of the parent div's height. Yet I want it to grab the 100% of the parent div on HOVER. So I want it to grab the 100px, which would be the parent div on hvoer.